# Implementing my own pow function in Java

Tags: java, algorithm

This is a popular interview question. Implementing my own pow function.
There are some popular recursive approaches available online but I'm trying to do it iteratively. The code works for n > 0, but I'm a little lost when it gets below 0. Here's my code.

```
 public double myPow(double x, int n) {

        if(x == 0) return 0;
        if(n == 0) return 1;

        double result = 1;
        if(n > 0 ){
            for(int i=1; i <= n; i++){
                result = result * x;
            } 
        }else{
            for(int i=1; i<= n; i++){

               //calculate the nth root 
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Any help appreciated with calculating the nth root.

Comment: The `n`th root is not when `n` is negative; x^(-n) = 1 / (x^n); the `n`th root is x^(1/n).

Comment: `myPow(0.0,0)` will return `0`. Is that what you want? It seems to be more appropriate to throw an exception instead.

Comment: @rgettman You're right my mistake.

Comment: @Gendarme yup you're right, fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can do that: (because x^(-n) = 1/x^n)

```
double positive_pow(double x, int n) {

        if(x == 0) return 0;
        if(n == 0) return 1;

        double result = 1;
        if(n > 0 ){
            for(int i=1; i <= n; i++){
                result = result * x;
            } 
        }else{
            for(int i=1; i<= n; i++){

               //calculate the nth root 
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

public double pow(double x, int n) {
    if (n > 0) return positive_pow(x, n);
    else if (n == 0) return 1;
    else return 1 / positive_pow(x, 0-n);
}
```

This is not the shortest way to implement this, but it is based on your base function and it's more clear than recursively calculating it or messing around with `Math` functions.

Answer (score 0):

This will work.

> This code will be returning result for negative powers as well. For the explanation I have used the variable `int p= x` for my calculation of negative powers.....

```
public static double Pow(int x,int n){
    if(x == 0) return 0;
    if(n == 0) return 1;

    double result = 1;
    if(n > 0 ){
        for(int i=1; i <= n; i++){
            result = result * x;
        } 
    }

    else{

        int p=x;

        for(int i=0; i>n; i--){
            if(result==1){
                result= 1/(result*x);
                result++;
            }

            else{
                p=p*x;  
                result= (1.0)*1/p;
            }

        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this, I wrote this one when I was practicing Java. The idea is 5^62=5^(32+16+8+4+2)=5^32*5^16*5^8*5^4*5^2, and in binary code, 62 is 00111110.

Here is the code:

```
double pow(double x, int n){
    int i;
    double result;
    result = 1;
    i = x;
    while(n != 0){
        if(n & 1 == 1){
            result *= i;
        }
        i *= i;
        n>>1;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: As mentioned I'm trying to find an iterative solution. I'm aware of this recursive option.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, I've updated my answer. @Zeus